# Print primes between 0 and 1,000,000 in C

Tags: c, recursion, global-variables, primes

I'm trying to write a recursive function to print all primes between 0 and 1,000,000:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isPrime(int);
int globalChk; //Global Variable

int main(){

    printf("2\n");

    int i;

    for(i=3;i<1000000;i++){

        globalChk = i/2;

         if(isPrime(i)==1){
             printf("%d",i);
             printf("\n");
         }
     }

    return 0;
}

int isPrime(int num){
    if(globalChk==1){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        if(num%globalChk==0) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
        globalChk = globalChk-1;
        isPrime(num);
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment it only seems to be printing 2 and 3 and nothing else. I can't seem to spot the problem. It might be the global variable.

Comment: It seems to be printing alright : http://ideone.com/fVe0DH, the solution however is very slow you may want to try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: you are calling isPrime way too many times, once a prime number is calculated why not use it to check the new value? Sieve of Eratosthenes as uSeemSurprised mentioned is an even better way of doing it.

Comment: `isPrime(num);` --> `return isPrime(num);`

Answer (score 4):

First of all

All prime numbers lies upto square-root

So you can outer loop by following

```
int n=sqrt(1000000);
for(int i=3;i<=n;i++)
{
}
```

you can improve isPrime function by following way

```
bool isPrime(int n) {

    // Corner cases

    if (n <= 1)  
        return false;
    if (n <= 3)
        return true;
    // This is checked so that we can skip 
    // middle five numbers in below loop

    if (n%2 == 0 || n%3 == 0) 
        return false;
    for (int i=5; i*i<=n; i=i+6)
        if (n%i == 0 || n%(i+2) == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

which is much faster